# Out of memory exception while converting images

Tags: c#

This is my code for converting images, all functions/methods work fine.

```
int height=0,width = 0;
        ImageFormat i;
        foreach (string pic in files)
        {
            Image temp = Image.FromFile(pic);
            if (whatisformat() != null)
                i = whatisformat();
            else
                i = GetImageFormat(temp);
            if (sizeselected()!=-1)
            {
                height = sizeselected();
                width = getwidth(height);
            }
            else
            {
                width = temp.Width;
                height = temp.Height;
            }
            Formatresizesave(temp, i, height, width, destination,Path.GetFileName(pic));
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
    }
```

I keep on getting an out of memory exceptions though I have plenty of RAM/memory on my pc.
I have over 60 gb free on my SSD and 32GBs of RAM and i still encounter the out of memory exception. What may cause the problem? In the tests i have done i only converted less than 6MBs of pictures.
By the way, Files is a list containing all file paths in a folder.
And destination is a global variable declared elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Dispose` on the image after you are done with it? By the way, you can get `OutOfMemoryException` without coming anywhere near your actual memory limit.

Comment: No i haven't, I'm not familiar with the Dispose method.. Sorry if I am a "Noob". How do i call the method and where should I call it?

Comment: It's quite likely that is is actually an invalid argument not a real OOM. GDI+ (which underlies `System.Drawing`) loves doing that. For example if your width/height parameters are negative, if target/source rectangles are outside the image,... All of these can cause an OOM exception.

Comment: Better than explicitly calling Dispose is a "using" block...

Comment: Please post the exception and stack trace and the code where the exception is occurring.

Comment: After (or immediately before) the `progressBar1.Value++` line write: `temp.Dispose()`. I suspect you have a `Bitmap` object under the hood and these get out of hand with memory if you don't dispose them manually. I'll write it up as an answer if it works.

Comment: I found the problem and i managed to add the dispose method, the dispose wasn't the problem, because i am still a new user I cannot post my answer... So thanks anyways everyone I express my greatest gratitude to you all.

Comment: @user3238509 I'm not aware of any self answering restrictions for new users. There should be an [Answer Your Question] button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I wasn't aloud to answer, there is an 8 hour waiting restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are building for x64, not x86. If you build for x86, your process will be limited to 2GB of RAM, and the fact that you have 32GB of physical RAM won't matter. You should also `Dispose` each image by using a `using` block.

```
    int height=0,width = 0;
    ImageFormat i;
    foreach (string pic in files)
    {
        using (Image temp = Image.FromFile(pic))
        {
            if (whatisformat() != null)
                i = whatisformat();
            else
                i = GetImageFormat(temp);
            if (sizeselected()!=-1)
            {
                height = sizeselected();
                width = getwidth(height);
            }
            else
            {
                width = temp.Width;
                height = temp.Height;
            }
            Formatresizesave(temp, i, height, width, destination,Path.GetFileName(pic));
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but RAM is really not the point here. The 2 GB limit is on address space. Whether that is backed by RAM or disk is besides the point.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen The fallback to hard drive for virtual memory is not reliable. On most systems, if you build for x86 then try to allocate 3GB worth of objects, the program will crash because allocations start to fail, even when there is, say, 8GB of RAM available.

Comment: @TimothyShields That's because there are only 2-3 GB of user-mode virtual address space per 32 bit process. Those programs crash because they run out of address space, not out of RAM. This is what Brian tries to tell you.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen @CodesInChaos Okay I see what you're saying now. Allocating a single enormous `byte[]` in a x86 process only takes 4 bytes of virtual address space.

Comment: @TimothyShields No, allocating a giant byte array will reserve the address space size required to support said array.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Are you making a distinction between address space and *virtual* address space? Same thing or different?

Comment: @TimothyShields please have a look at this series of posts for a good walkthrough http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx